# How to measure size of gear using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on project where I have to measure size of gear. I have already find contour of the gear and teeth of the gear. Now I want to measure its real world size with 100 percent accuracy real world dimension of gear is 53mm in outer diameter and 43mm in inner diameter and teeth size is 5mm, and also if I remove this gear and place large gear it also measure its correct diameter

[image: my image is here]

```
# count outer teeth
c = max(max_c, key=cv2.contourArea)
hull = cv2.convexHull(c, clockwise=True, returnPoints=False)
hull1 = []
for i in hull:
    if len(hull1) == 0:
        hull1.append(i)
    else:
        last = hull1[-1]
        diff = c[i] - c[last]
        if cv2.norm(diff) > 10:
            hull1.append(i)
hull1 = np.asarray(hull1)
hull2 = hull1[:-1].copy()

# count inner teeth
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(c, hull2)
#print(defects)
inner_points = []
for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
    far = tuple(c[f][0])
    #print(far)
    inner_points.append(f)
```

Comment: What is accuracy?

Comment: real world outer and inner diameter of gear is 53 and 43...I am getting 52 and 42. and teeth size is 5 getting 6

Comment: all dimensions are in mm

Comment: Are you using Telecentric Lenses? Is your camera calibrated?

Comment: why are you getting numbers without decimals? where do you introduce the scale factor that turns pixels into millimeters?

Comment: i am using fisheye lens

Comment: i am getting output with decimal. and i have calculated pixel permatric and using formula lenght in pixel / pixel permatric . i am getting output